# Update with multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

i am using UPDATE to update all records in the table with value from another table:

```
UPDATE x.ADR_TEMP SET LOCATIONID = (SELECT ID FROM x.OBJECTRELATIONSHIP WHERE PROPERTYCLASS = 'PHYSICALLOCATION')
```

in both tables are the same number of records. I just need to read id from one table and put them into another.

I have error: `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

I am new in this subject and suspect that  solution is very simple. Please help me

Comment: x.ADR_TEMP and x.OBJECTRELATIONSHIP have any relations like foreign keys?

Comment: How are `ADR_TEMP` and `OBJECTRELATIONSHIP` related to each other?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE x.ADR_TEMP SET LOCATIONID = (
                                     SELECT ID 
                                     FROM x.OBJECTRELATIONSHIP 
                                     WHERE PROPERTYCLASS = 'PHYSICALLOCATION' AND x.ADR_TEMP.relatedKey = x.OBJECTRELATIONSHIP.relatedKey )
```

if your tables are related to each other with some way like this(relatedKey is a column which  relates to the second table mentioned), you can try this one.(not sure or perfect)